# Unhiding subviews in stack view causing weird animation

Tags: ios, swift

I have a `UIStackView` pinned to the bottom right hand side of the screen with some items in it. Initially everything is hidden. When I unhide one subview, which is of a fixed width, it seems to animate by flying in from the left hand side of the screen. I haven't set a width for the stack view, because items in it can change width. How can I stop this weird animation?

Comment: Could you provide some code snippet here, so it will ease to understand what you have tried.

Comment: @guru All the views are setup through my storyboard, all I'm doing is saying `myView.isHidden = false` for a specific view inside the stackview.

Comment: In storyboard, what is ur myView's X,Y,Width & Height?

Comment: @McDonal_11 It has a width of 100, then the height is dynamic based on the text in the label inside it. I haven't set any x or y constraints (apart from pinning the label to the edge of my view) as the stack view manages that

Comment: have to see ur Storyboard Constraints for Stackview and its subviews

Comment: *"(apart from pinning the label to the edge of my view)"* -- do you mean pinning the **stack view** to the edge? Or did you actually add a trailing constraint to the label?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out it was something to do with animating the update of layouts of views pinned to the edge of the `UIStackView`. Removing the animation make it work fine.

Answer (score 1):

It happens a lot in UIStackviews. I solved it by the following code:

After setting your view unhide, try using

```
layoutIfNeeded()
```

in next line.